# Google cloud vision OCR reads the same letter more than once

Tags: ocr, google-cloud-vision

I'm using google cloud vision OCR to extract text from receipt images and came across this weird issue where the OCR reads the same letter twice but with different coordinates.
To visualize the issue, I draw rectangles around each letter using the coordinates returned from the API:
This is the part of the image with the issue:

[image: example]

As you can see, there are overlapping rectangles on the 'M' and the 'a'.
The result is something like this:
   '''MMaay 10, 2019'''

Why this is happening?
Is there a way to fix it?

I tried to change the image format from bmp to png. The only difference is that the overlapping rectangle is moved from the 'a' to the 'y'.